# How to install Rundeck in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, rundeck

I install Rundeck following [this](http://rundeck.org/downloads.html).I install it by **.jar ,.deb or .war** but it all failed.I have installed java8.

Comment: How does it fail? The instalation is pretty simple, I've just run it in notime: 

``wget http://dl.bintray.com/rundeck/rundeck-maven/rundeck-launcher-2.6.7.jar`` and then

``java -jar rundeck-launcher-2.6.7.jar`` and then 
navigate browser to http://localhost:4440

Actually the documentation mentions it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Install rundeck by launcher](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/installation.html#installing-with-launcher) This document is more detailed.After install it,you should modify something. Use your **server ip** replace **localhost** or you may go to http://ubuntu:4440/menu/home after login admin.

- $RDECK_HOME/etc/framework.properties
  framework.server.url
- $RDECK_HOME/etc/preferences.properties
  framework.server.url
- $RDECK_HOME/server/config/rundeck-config.properties
  rundeck-config.properties

Comment: Your link has expired. I'm still looking for an answer, do you have any tips?